# Consecutive SecureString hashes don't match

Tags: powershell, securestring

An encrypted password is stored in my .ps1 script. When setting up the script in a new environment, user has to manually configure this password at the beginning of the script. I've set up a switch parameter so the user can run the script that way and it will give the user the required hash. However, when prompting to input the password twice to make sure there are no typos - or such - in it I cannot get the password hashes to match. To demonstrate, I can manually enter this in PowerShell *twice in a row* and get different results entering the exact same password:

```
Read-Host -AsSecureString 'Enter password' | ConvertFrom-SecureString
```

This is with or without `-Key` or `-SecureKey` parameter. How can I prompt the user for password (twice to make sure they match) and if/when they do match, output the password hash?

Comment: I don't think you can do that, the [DPAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) (which is called in the background when you need a `SecureString`) derives a session key dependent on a random salt when encrypting your string. You'll have to decrypt them to compare

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very pretty solution, but does the job decrypting the given passwords and then comparing them:

```
if ([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringtoBSTR(($enterpw | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key))) -ne [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringtoBSTR(($enterpw2 | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key)))) {
    Write-Host "Given passwords do not match"
    Break
}
```